# C++ Reading From File Loop Messing Up

Tags: c++

I have a problem with a simple file read.  I have 4 four long lines of T/F's with a count at the beginning.  I read in with a myfile >> count, and myfile >> value to get the values with a while with the count to finish it off the line and goto the next but I have a problem going to the third line for some reason.  Not sure how to get the data file on here...    Thanks for looking!

```
int main() {
    ifstream myfile;
    int count;
    string value;

    myfile.open("branches.txt");

    while(!myfile.eof()) {
        myfile >> count;
        cout << count << endl;

        while(count > 0) {
            myfile >> value;
            count--;
            //cout << value;
        }

        myfile >> count;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please update this post with the exact contents of your file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be attempting to read the `count` twice per line: at the beginning and end of the while loop.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `feof()` it just tells you what the result of the previous read was. The correct way to read a file is

```
while( read( file, buffer ) ) 
{    
    //do something 
}
```

Comment: In this case `while(myfile >> count)`.